# Can't write into a file, java swing

Tags: java

I want to write into a file, but It doesn't seem to write into it, the files name is Grade output.txt...

for example when i run the program, the input for quiz 1 : 90.. which is Q1 it supposed to add on the file after stopped running.

```
 'try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Grade output.txt"));
                //for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    out.write(Q1 + " ");



System.out.println(Q1);

                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
```

'

'

```
 import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
      import java.io.IOException;
```

public class AICS_grade_applet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

//  Label titleLabel = new Label(" Grading System", Label.CENTER);

```
Label prelimsQ1Label = new Label("Quiz 1", Label.LEFT);
TextField prelimsQ1Field = new TextField(10);

Label prelimsQ2Label = new Label("Quiz 2", Label.LEFT);
TextField prelimsQ2Field = new TextField(10);

Label prelimsCSLabel = new Label("Quiz 3", Label.LEFT);
TextField prelimsCSField = new TextField(10);

Label prelimsEXLabel = new Label("Quiz 4", Label.LEFT);
TextField prelimsEXField = new TextField(10);

Label midtermQ1Label = new Label("Quiz 5", Label.LEFT);
TextField midtermQ1Field = new TextField(10);

Label midtermQ2Label = new Label("Quiz 6", Label.LEFT);
TextField midtermQ2Field = new TextField(10);

Label midtermCSLabel = new Label("Quiz 7", Label.LEFT);
TextField midtermCSField = new TextField(10);

Label midtermEXLabel = new Label("Quiz 8", Label.LEFT);
TextField midtermEXField = new TextField(10);

Label finalsQ1Label = new Label("Quiz 9", Label.LEFT);
TextField finalsQ1Field = new TextField(10);

Label finalsQ2Label = new Label("Quiz 10", Label.LEFT);
TextField finalsQ2Field = new TextField(10);

Label finalsCSLabel = new Label("Quiz 11", Label.LEFT);
TextField finalsCSField = new TextField(10);

Label finalsEXLabel = new Label("Quiz 12", Label.LEFT);
TextField finalsEXField = new TextField(10);

Button computeButton = new Button("  Compute  ");
Button clearButton = new Button("    Clear   ");

Label gradeLabel = new Label("Grade:   ", Label.RIGHT);
TextField gradeField = new TextField(10);

Label statusLabel = new Label("Status:   ", Label.RIGHT);
TextField statusField = new TextField("enter the data", 10);

public void init() { // begin init-------------------------------

    setBackground(Color.white);
    setForeground(Color.red);
//  add(titleLabel);

    add(prelimsQ1Label);
    add(prelimsQ1Field);
    prelimsQ1Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(prelimsQ2Label);
    add(prelimsQ2Field);
    prelimsQ2Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(prelimsCSLabel);
    add(prelimsCSField);
    prelimsCSField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(prelimsEXLabel);
    add(prelimsEXField);
    prelimsEXField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(midtermQ1Label);
    add(midtermQ1Field);
    midtermQ1Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(midtermQ2Label);
    add(midtermQ2Field);
    midtermQ2Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(midtermCSLabel);
    add(midtermCSField);
    midtermCSField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(midtermEXLabel);
    add(midtermEXField);
    midtermEXField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(finalsQ1Label);
    add(finalsQ1Field);
    finalsQ1Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(finalsQ2Label);
    add(finalsQ2Field);
    finalsQ2Field.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(finalsCSLabel);
    add(finalsCSField);
    finalsCSField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(finalsEXLabel);
    add(finalsEXField);
    finalsEXField.setForeground(Color.red);

    add(computeButton);
    computeButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(clearButton);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);

    add(gradeLabel);
    add(gradeField);
    gradeField.setForeground(Color.gray);

    add(statusLabel);
    add(statusField);
    statusField.setForeground(Color.blue);

} // end init

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent yhan) {

    // declare object strings
    String strprelimsQ1 = new String(prelimsQ1Field.getText());
    String strprelimsQ2 = new String(prelimsQ2Field.getText());
    String strprelimsCS = new String(prelimsCSField.getText());
    String strprelimsEX = new String(prelimsEXField.getText());
    String strmidtermQ1 = new String(midtermQ1Field.getText());
    String strmidtermQ2 = new String(midtermQ2Field.getText());
    String strmidtermCS = new String(midtermCSField.getText());
    String strmidtermEX = new String(midtermEXField.getText());
    String strfinalsQ1 = new String(finalsQ1Field.getText());
    String strfinalsQ2 = new String(finalsQ2Field.getText());
    String strfinalsCS = new String(finalsCSField.getText());
    String strfinalsEX = new String(finalsEXField.getText());

    if (yhan.getSource() == computeButton)

    {
        if (strprelimsQ1.equals("")) {
            prelimsQ1Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strprelimsQ2.equals("")) {
            prelimsQ2Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strprelimsCS.equals("")) {
            prelimsCSField.setText("0");
        }

        if (strprelimsEX.equals("")) {
            prelimsEXField.setText("0");
        }

        if (strmidtermQ1.equals("")) {
            midtermQ1Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strmidtermQ2.equals("")) {
            midtermQ2Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strmidtermCS.equals("")) {
            midtermCSField.setText("0");
        }

        if (strmidtermEX.equals("")) {
            midtermEXField.setText("0");
        }

        if (strfinalsQ1.equals("")) {
            finalsQ1Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strfinalsQ2.equals("")) {
            finalsQ2Field.setText("0");
        }

        if (strfinalsCS.equals("")) {
            finalsCSField.setText("0");
        }

        if (strfinalsEX.equals("")) {
            finalsEXField.setText("0");
        }

        // Converting input to values
        int Q1 = Integer.parseInt(prelimsQ1Field.getText());
        int Q2 = Integer.parseInt(prelimsQ2Field.getText());
        int Q3 = Integer.parseInt(prelimsQ2Field.getText());
        int Q4 = Integer.parseInt(prelimsEXField.getText());
        int Q5 = Integer.parseInt(midtermQ1Field.getText());
        int Q6 = Integer.parseInt(midtermQ2Field.getText());
        int Q7 = Integer.parseInt(midtermQ2Field.getText());
        int Q8 = Integer.parseInt(midtermEXField.getText());
        int Q9 = Integer.parseInt(finalsQ1Field.getText());
        int Q10 = Integer.parseInt(finalsQ2Field.getText());
        int Q11 = Integer.parseInt(finalsQ2Field.getText());
        int Q12 = Integer.parseInt(finalsEXField.getText());

        // Calculations
        double grade = (Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4
                + Q5 + Q6 + Q7 + Q8 + Q9 + Q10+ Q11+ Q12) / 12;

        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Grade output.txt"));
                //for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    out.write(Q1 + " ");



System.out.println(Q1);

                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}

        // Output grade
        gradeField.setText("" + Math.round(grade));

        if (grade < 75) {
            statusField.setText("failed");
        } else {
            statusField.setText("Pass");
        }

        if (grade > 100) {
            statusField.setText("You may have invalid input");
        }
    } // end if computeButton

    if (yhan.getSource() == clearButton) {
        gradeField.setText("");
        prelimsQ1Field.setText("");
        prelimsQ2Field.setText("");
        prelimsCSField.setText("");
        prelimsEXField.setText("");
        midtermQ1Field.setText("");
        midtermQ2Field.setText("");
        midtermCSField.setText("");
        midtermEXField.setText("");
        finalsQ1Field.setText("");
        finalsQ2Field.setText("");
        finalsCSField.setText("");
        finalsEXField.setText("");
        statusField.setText("reenter the data");

    } // end if clearButton

} // end actionperformed
```

} // end class
'

Comment: Why did you add all that irrelevant code?

Comment: Don't ever ignore exceptions. If there is an IOException, you won't know about it because you catch it and ignore it. An IOException is thrown when there is an IO error, and its type and message tell you what the problem is. Add e.printStackTrace() to the catch block at least. Ans add traces to the code to at least know if the IO code is ever executed.

Comment: Just added the stack trace, still no addition to the .txt file

Comment: @ClearMist Did you get an error message? If you get an error message, you most likely won't get any addition to your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless signed, an applet cannot write to the file system. You can either sign the applet or deploy re-develop the applet as an application using [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Read:

- [Signing Applets Using RSA Certificates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html)
- [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html)
- [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: Hi, how do you sign the applet, can you provide me with any resources?

Comment: Have added the links as requested but would suggest that a simple Swing application rather than an applet is more appropriate here